# Not able to publish image to std_msg/Image

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-melodic, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a publisher code that publishes an Image to a topic. But, whenever I run the code, I get an error. The code I have written is below -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def main():
rospy.init_node('Tennis Ball Publisher', anonymous = True)

pub = rospy.Publisher("tennis_ball_image", Image, queue_size = 10)

rate = rospy.Rate(1)

while (True):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    pub.publish(frame)

    rate.sleep()
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error that I get on running the code -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tennis_ball_publisher.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "tennis_ball_publisher.py", line 20, in main
    pub.publish(frame)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 879, in publish
    data = args_kwds_to_message(self.data_class, args, kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 122, in args_kwds_to_message
    return data_class(*args)

  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sensor_msgs/msg/_Image.py", line 78, in __init__
    super(Image, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 294, in __init__
    raise TypeError("Invalid number of arguments, args should be %s"%str(self.__slots__)+" args are"+str(args))
TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['header', 'height', 'width', 'encoding', 'is_bigendian', 'step', 'data'] args are(None,)
```

I suspect that the error is in the way I am publishing the frame but I am not able to rectify it. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329914/not-able-to-publish-image-to-std_msg/image/) by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to publish the OpenCV image directly. From what I can recall, you need to convert it to an `Image` message before you can publish it. To do that use, `cv_bridge`. Here's a brief example that should help you get started (I've included only the bare minimum, for more info see the [tutorial on the wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython#An_example_ROS_node))

```
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

...

bridge = CvBridge()

...

pub.publish(bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, "bgr8"))
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-08-05**:
Thanks for your help! Really sorry for not responding earlier. I have been a bit busy the last few days.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-05**:
No worries